# commit and rollback for specified cases

Tags: mysql, transactions, mysql-workbench, commit, rollback

can we put a `check` (sort of)   to-

1. > Check if data is committed to database only when the operation is successfully completed.
2. > Data should be rolled back in case of failed transactions.

like this one-

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_fail`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE customer SET age= 20 WHERE name='stark';
    UPDATE customer SET age= 20 WHERE name='brian'; -- fail as there is no name as brian in the table customer
    IF `_rollback` THEN
        SELECT 'The transaction has failed' AS 'Result';
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        SELECT 'The transaction was successful' AS 'Result';
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Its mine modified version of one of the answers in stackoverflow itself.I was thinking of using this to solve the above mentioned points but when i call the procedure the call runs successfully but no rows are affected.Why is that ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is too vague. Please add details.

Comment: Like [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

There is Autocommit properties in mysql. You will need set AUTOCOMMIT=0 (this set the autocommit false), after that you can issue COMMIT or ROLLBACK at the end of query according to your condition.

```
1. INSERT INTO table_name ...;

2. COMMIT; --  confirm your changes

        OR

3. ROLLBACK; --  undo your  changes
```